# Tasks or meetings not shown under calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When opening outlook, I used to see under my calendar (right side of screen) all my next 3-4 meetings of the day.   Now it only shows a calendar but no meetings or tasks for the day.

Comment: it is telling me that the path specified is not valid...where would my calendar be?

Comment: That depends on the calendar. Is it hosted on an Exchange Server/Office 365 or some other CalDAV server somewhere, or is it a local calendar, stored only on your PC?

Comment: Also - it might help people answer your question if you stated which version of Outlook you're running (eg Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013 or Outlook 2011 for Mac).

Comment: Apologies, it is Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of Outlook so I will assume it is the current one on Windows.

Click on `Mail` view if not selected already.  Then from the top menu select the `VIEW` tab.  Under the `To-Do Bar` drop down list select `Calendar`.

[image: Outlook 2013 View]